# How to use the Initialization and Finalization command in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

When I generate new application project on Delphi, the first Line of Implementation in source Project1.pas is the following.

```
Application.Initialize; 
Application.CreateForm(Tform1, form1);
Application.Run;
```

Then in event OnCreate of Form1 I realize all `initialization` I need, like
Open FdConnections, Activate Queries and so on.
I am also closing all Queries and Connection in OnClose of form. Would be `Initialization` and `Finalization` one good alternative to do do that? What's this commands purpose, and what different of OnCreate?

```
var Form1:TForm1;
Implementation

Initialization
Begin
FdConnection1.Open;
FdQuery1.open;
FdQuery2.Open;
...
End;
Finalization
Begin
FdQuery1.Close
...
FdConnection.Close;
End; {Could It works?}
```

Comment: This is explained in the documentation

Comment: Which object, if any are FDConnection1 an FDQuery1&2 members of, or are they global variables?  If they are members of an object, that object needs to be created first, and then they do.  I think you may have a basic misunderstanding of Initialization  and Finalization sections and object lifetimes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - the documentation for Initialization sucks. For example, it tells that Initialization is called somewhere at program startup. Thanks Emba. Could not have been more accurately documented!! https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Programs_and_Units_(Delphi)#The_Initialization_Section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Initialization** and **Finalization** sections execute exactly once, no matter how many instances of a Form are created.  Contrast that with the **OnCreate**, **OnClose**, and **OnDestroy** events of a Form, which execute once for each instance.

In your example, the Form in question is only created once, so the difference really applies more to Forms that are (or can be) created (instantiated) multiple times, whether each instance is closed or not.

Comment: Just not mentioning OP's original reference to `Application.Initialize;`...

Comment: @jerry Application.Initialize is unrelated to unit initialization and finalization.

Comment: More to the point, Initialization and Finalization sections relate to the unit, not to any classes that happen to be declared in it, and nor to Application.Initialize.

Comment: @David Yes, I know, it was one of the very first things OP put in question. Obviously that's not what OP was asking about though, which is what I thought.

Answer (score 4):

To follow the order of events when a Delphi application starts up, try the following:

1. Create an `Initialization` section in your Form1's unit, put some inconsequential code
   in it and set a debug breakpoint on it. The point of this code is simply so that you can
   put a breakpoint on it.
2. Create a `Finalization` section in your Form1's unit, put some code in that and put
   a breakpoint on it.
3. Put a break point on Application.Initialize in your .Dpr file.
4. Compile and run the app.
5. The debugger will stop on the breakpoint you created in step 1.  If you view the call stack,
   you will see that the code is being called as a result of being called from the RTL routine
   `InitUnits` which calls in turn the initialization section of each unit compiled into your
   .Exe.  The exact order they are called is determined by the compiler at compile time
   and presumably determined by a depth-first traversal of the USEd units.
6. Next, the debugger will stop on the Application.Initialize BP in the .Dpr file.  By the time
   execution reaches there, the `Initialization` sections of all the units compiled into the
   .Exe will have been called.
7. When you close the application, the debugger will stop on the `Finalization` BP you set
   in step 2.  If you trace out of it, you will find that it calls the `Finalization` sections
   of the units in the reverse order to the order the `Initialization` sections were called. And
   these `Initialization` and `Finalization` sections are called only once per execution of
   the .Exe.

It ought to be apparent from the above that the calls to the Initialization/Finalization
sections are unrelated to whether any classes in the units are ever instantiated.  The prime
reason to instantiate a class in an `Initialization` section is to ensure that the class
instance exists before Application.Initialize is called (or the equivalent of `Main()` is
called in a console application).